# (How) Can the typical continuous probability distributions be derived from elementary distributions?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

There are certain probability spaces which I regard as very basic and very easy to match with physical intuition.
These are for example:

1. The Bernoulli $\mathrm{Ber}_p$ distribution with paramter $p$ on $\Omega= \{0,1\}$.
2. The Laplace distribution on $\Omega = \{1, \dots, n\}$.
3. The Lebesgue measure on $\Omega = [0,1]$.

I know how a few of the standard discrete probability measures can be constructed from the above (in particular the Bernoulli distribution).

For example, if I consider the product probability space $(\{0,1\}^n, P(\{0,1\}^n), \mathrm{Ber}_p^{\otimes n} )$, consider the sum map $\Sigma \colon \{0,1\}^n \to \{0, \dots, n\}$, then the image measure $\Sigma_*( \mathrm{Ber}_p^{\otimes n})$ is the binomial distribution $\mathrm{Bin}_{n,p}$.

Or, if I consider the infinite product $(\{0,1\}, P(\{0,1\}), \mathrm{Ber}_p)^\mathbb{N}$ and consider the map $X \colon \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$, $(a_1, a_2, \dots) \mapsto \inf\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid a_n = 1\}$, then the image measure $X_*(\mathrm{Ber}_p^{\otimes \mathbb{N}})$ is the geometric distribution with parameter $p$.

The above constructions are directly related with real world interpretations of the respective distributions.

I wonder if I can in a similar way construct continuous distributions like the Poisson distribution, the exponential distribution or the Gauß distribution from more basic ones (perhaps using the Lebesgue measure as a basic building block).

Comment: If $F$ is the probability function for a a continous distribution and $U$ is a uniformly distributed random variable then $F^{-1}(U)$ has probability function $F$. So you can get any continuous distribution from the uniform one

Comment: Using the concept of the quantile function, what B.Martin said generalizes to any 1D distribution.

Comment: (The technique in question is called the probability integral transformation.)